# Updating an Dynamics CRM Opportunity once it is closed

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Once an Opportunity is closed, is it possible through the CRM SDK to update Opportunity custom fields without temporarily reopening and closing the Opportunity?  Can the CRM SDK override the logic that doesn't allow the Opportunity to be updated once closed?

Answer (score 3):

You can update an inactive opportunity via the `OrganizationService` or the OData service without having to reopen it.

Comment: As a related aside, you can update closed records like this in Workflows too. There are exceptions, activities being most notable. But Opportunity is fair game.